# File ended while scanning use of \emph citation, I suspect you have forgotten a }

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have an error with a citation in my document with bibtex. I receive the error

```
Runaway argument?

{, 1189--1232. \par \bibitem [Gradeci {\rm et~al.}, 2020]{gradeci2020\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \emph .
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.502 \bibliography{biblio}
                           
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

Here is the citation :

```
@article{friedman2001greedy,
    title={Greedy function approximation: a gradient boosting machine},
    author={Friedman, Jerome H},
    journal={Annals of statistics},
    pages={1189--1232},
    year={2001},
    publisher={JSTOR},
}
```

I suspected maybe an incorrect character so I rewritted manually the citation, I checked for missing } but it seems okay, I tried to remove the ":" but same problem.
I don't understand where the problem is coming from and it happens even if this citation is alone in the document, can you help me ?

I'm using

```
\bibliographystyle{cell}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

and `\cite`

---

Here is the minimal amount of code to create the error :
The `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\cite{friedman2001greedy}
\bibliographystyle{cell}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

The `biblio.bib`

```
@article{friedman2001greedy,
    title={Greedy function approximation a gradient boosting machine},
    author={Friedman, Jerome H},
    journal={Annals of statistics},
    pages={1189--1232},
    year={2001},
    publisher={JSTOR},
}
```

I receive the following  `.bbl`

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Friedman, 2001]{friedman2001greedy}
Friedman, J.~H. (2001{\rm{}}).
\newblock Greedy function approximation a gradient boosting machine.
\newblock {\rm Annals of statistics } \emph{, 1189--1232.

\end{thebibliography}
```

And the following error

```
Runaway argument?

{, 1189--1232. \par \end {thebibliography} 
! File ended while scanning use of \emph .
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \bibliography{biblio}
                         
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

 main.tex, line 9
LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \end{document}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

edit : The cause of error was a missing volume field, I corrected it by adding it :

```
@article{friedman2001greedy,
    title={Greedy function approximation a gradient boosting machine},
    author={Friedman, Jerome H},
    journal={Annals of statistics},
    pages={1189--1232},
    year={2001},
    publisher={JSTOR},
    volume={29},
    number={5}
}
```

Comment: The fail-proof approach is to comment out the citations until you figure out which one is cause the problem.  It's also possible that you forgot a comma, not a `}`.

Comment: And as someone else had commented, the error seems to be referring to `Gradeci`, not `Friedman`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Gradeci is my last citation in the document. Sorry for putting the error for my document and not from the minimalist example.

Here is the correct message.

```{, 1189--1232. \par \end {thebibliography} 
! File ended while scanning use of \emph .
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.502 \bibliography{biblio}
                           
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.```

And it's this citation the problem. I tried it alone

Comment: you have not provided a minimal example? Nothing here allows anyone to see the cause of the error. start by deleting the bbl file, running latex and then re-run bibtex, if you still get an error show the bib file and generated bbl

Comment: I updated my first post with more details

Comment: bibtex is generating `\newblock {\rm Annals of statistics } \emph{, 1189--1232.` with no closing `}` so that will never work. Either you got a bibtex error that you have not told us about (show the `.blg` bibtex log) or the bibtex style that you are using is broken

Answer (score 2):

Running bibtex on your example gives the error

```
`volume' is a missing field, not a string, for entry friedman2001greedy
```

because the missing field the generated bbl file is incomplete

```
\newblock {\rm Annals of statistics } \emph{, 1189--1232.
```

and the emph command is never closed.

Never ignore errors from tex or bibtex, the output is rarely usable after an error.

add a volume such as

```
@article{friedman2001greedy,
    title={Greedy function approximation a gradient boosting machine},
    author={Friedman, Jerome H},
    journal={Annals of statistics},
    pages={1189--1232},
    year={2001},
    publisher={JSTOR},
    volume=2
}
```

(I just made up 2 here)

and re-run bibtex and the generated bbl looks like

```
\newblock {\rm Annals of statistics } \emph{2}, 1189--1232.
```

and LaTeX will input this without error.

Comment: Thank you, it was this.
I didn't know that .bbl file will give me more information